# loop on execution of script in an other folder

Tags: python, operating-system, working-directory

first question,
I want to run this "something.exe" on an other folder "Magpie" include in the one of my main.py 
I try this:

```
 os.system("Magpie\\SelfCalibHsamiPDDS.exe \"Magpie_ConfigCalib_Case000.json\"")
```

I dont get an error but nothing happen too...

Second: I need to loop this operation on many folder, I don't fint the good way to deal with the " and ' my goal is to replace 'Magpie' by a string in a list to fill the space and gen a new call with a different folder...

for exemple what I try...

```
for ii in namelist:
    os.system(['\"' + ii + '\SelfCalibHsamiPDDS.exe \"Magpie_ConfigCalib_Case000.json\""'])
```

Comment: finaly find my error for the first question, directory change not on the good part of the code. Must be: os.system("SelfCalibHsamiPDDS.exe \"Magpie\\Magpie_ConfigCalib_Case000.json\"")

Answer (score 0):

Finaly find all solution, prob was not where I was looking. 
mislocate the folder call and after that my method to loop was working too

good code :

```
os.system('copy \"Magpie\\Magpie_ConfigCalib.json\" \"Magpie_ConfigCalib_Case000\".json')
```

and

```
for ii in var:
     os.system('"SelfCalibHsamiPDDS.exe \"' + ii + '\\Magpie_ConfigCalib_Case000.json\""')
```

if someone have better proposition Im open to all idea

Comment: You could use string formatting: `cmd = f'"SelfCalibHsamiPDDS.exe \{ii}\\Magpie_ConfigCalib_Case000.json\""'` or `cmd = '"SelfCalibHsamiPDDS.exe \{}\\Magpie_ConfigCalib_Case000.json\""'.format(ii)`